# angular routing does not load template

Tags: angularjs

I am using asp mvc 4 and angular js.

this is my html when the application loads(Course/Index):

```
<div class="container" ng-app="appModule">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="/Course/List">Course Managment</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Course/Assignment">Course Assignment</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
```

and this is my appModule:

```
angular.module("appModule", ["ngRoute", "CoursesListCtrl", "repositoryBaseFactory"])
    .config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
           .when("/Course/List", {
               templateUrl: "templates/coursesList.html",
               caseInsensitiveMatch: true
           });
    }]);
```

When clicking on the `Course Managment` link I want the `coursesList.html` to be loaded. Instead the framework is trying to go the server and find action `List` and returns an error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try using ui-view  in html instead of ng-view , since you are using ui-router

Comment: try this one also  : </a  <li><ui-sref=="coursesList">Course Managment</a></li>

Comment: A few things, CourseListCtrl and repositoryBaseFactory probably shuold be in the same module instead of dependencies.

Comment: And you to use # in your href="#/Course/List", otherwise the browser are going to ask the server for that page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a ng-href="#/Course/List">Course Managment</a>
```